# Did the turret shown in this picture belong to a German battleship?

Tags: united-states

[image]

As @Lennart Regebro observed in an [answer to another question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/9929/1401), while the gun turret shown in the picture above is claimed to be German and from WWI, it doesn't look like German gun turrets.

Yet, @jwenting, too, agreeing with Lennart Regebro, added that the design of that turret does not conform to neither WW1 nor WW2 German capital ship turrets and pointed out that that piece did not even belong to a battleship.

So, incidentaly, it is arosed an interesting discussion that, as far as I can tell, deserves a new topic and, hence, the following question.

Can anybody show or indicate a reliable reference explaing whether that turret belonged, as it is claimed elsewhere, to a German battleship?

Comment: please provide the link to that question

Comment: In my answer I provide a link to a picture of a US ship, with a turret of a very similar design. As such this question was answered already there, so the purpose of this question eludes me.

Comment: @bhau bhau, here is the link http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9929/can-anyone-explain-the-reason-why-a-wreck-of-a-battleship-lies-in-the-nevada-des

Comment: @Lennart, I'm not so sure the link you provided answers to the question, that's all.

Comment: I get the feeling that you in most of your questions have an agenda and get disappointed when you get another answer that the one you were looking for. I'm hoping I'm wrong here. But this gun turret is obviously not from a German ship, and I don't know why you want it to be.

Comment: @Lennart, -1 again and again; my agenda ended on 21-12-2012 with the Maya's calendar, though.

Comment: I believe that [the answer][1]  is in the original question.


  [1]: http://history.stackexchange.com/a/9939/1401

Answer (score 6):

No, it is a US style gun turret, and hence does not come from a German ship, but a US one.

[image: Picture of similar gun turret]

This picture is most likely of [USS Salt Lake City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensacola_class_cruiser) or [USS Northampton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northampton_class_cruiser), taken [March 25 1941 in Brisbane](http://blogs.slq.qld.gov.au/jol/2013/07/30/brisbane-rejoices-as-the-us-navy-comes-to-town-march-1941/). Both used this type of turrets. It was used on  the [Pensacola class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Pensacola_%28CA-24%29), the [Northampton class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northampton_class_cruiser) and the [Portland class](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNUS_8-55_mk9_pics.htm).

Here is a picture of USS Pensacola in 1945:

[image: USS Pensacola]

As comparison, here is a page with pictures of some [German warship gun turrets](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNGER_12-50_skc12_pics.htm).

There is absolutely no doubt that the turret in the picture is a US type turret.

Comment: -1, I'm not sure how the link you provided answers to the question. Please, cite a reliable source, congettures are discouraged as per the FAQs.

Comment: @AarãoXistoSalazar A picture of the same sort of gun turret on a US warship is not a conclusion. The only way to find a more reliable source is to find an original source about that exact turret. For that you are likely to have to go to Washington archives and dig for a couple of days. Assuming that they are declassified.

Comment: Could you highlight the features of the battleship turret that convince you that they match the one in the Nevada desert?  They don't look similar to me. (I'm not challenging your conclusion, I'm looking to learn something).

Comment: Lennart, -1 again, and think of that jwenting, who, as he himself claims, is an expert of German turrets, pointed out that that piece did not even belong to a battleship, anyway.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The square shape, with rounded corners, sloping front, the little hatchets on the fronts, the ladders that enable you to climb up on top, and the hand-railing on the sides.

Comment: @AarãoXistoSalazar: Yes, jwenting, expert or not, agrees that it is *not* a German turret. Yet you persist in claiming that it might be.

Comment: @AarãoXistoSalazar I said NOT a German ship. Unless you can prove that a well documented Amerian cruiser of WW2 design is actually a WW1 German battleship, you're in the wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the gun or turret but the landscape looks the Idaho Falls Nuclear Laboratory which was originally a heavy naval gun testing/register range.  The range was edged out after the war by the nuke people needing a vast space to set up labs for test reactors and research.  An interesting item is that several inherited large naval guns in storage were cast radioactive free and were invaluable in use for various experiments requiring radioactive free metal.  It seems that all metal cast after the Trinity test, bombs in Japan, tests in the Pacific, the Hanford Site "Green Run" (you should research that!  Woohoo!), the Nevada Test Site tests, and whatever radioactivity Russia was spewing into the air, they couldn't find any radioactive free metal.  There was at least a slight trace of it in all metal cast.  The naval cannons left there were free of it.  (to read more-Google:  "Proving the Principle")
I suspect there is a slight trace in everything since then.